# Why the destination address come before the source address in ethernet header

Tags: networking, ethernet

I know in the ethernet header the destination address comes before the source address. Can you please explain me why is that ?

Comment: yes of course a pointless question and it was asked in an university assignment of mine. I asked here since I also can't figure it out why. If I could find any point then I won't bother to ask here  :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this kind of questions is often futile (they had to pick one order; which one they choose might be random), there is indeed one very valid reason for this:

In order to work efficiently, the receiver wants to read the address of a packet very easy, perhaps even with the help of hardware (FPGA or ASIC).

And for this, it is handy to have this address at the very beginning.

Comment: thanks a lot for your thoughtful answer. :) Yes that reason is fair enough.

Comment: @IreshaRubasinghe You're welcome. It would be nice if you'd accept my answer by clicking on ✓.

Comment: have clicked already :D but it won't be visible till I get required amount of reputation :)